# Issue on update data by notifyDataSetChanged in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I used the Recycler View to show my list of data. I called web service and get the data from server and update current **ArrayList** with server data.
This is how i fill the data in my current ArrayList.

```
mAlUotesDatas.clear();
mAlUotesDatas = (ArrayList<BillBoardData>) webservice.data;
mUotesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and apply **notifyDataSetChanged()**  to reflect in the list of data but it doesn't reflect the list. In `mAlUotesDatas` it shows the updated data but it doesn't shows the updated list of data.

After that i change it like

```
mAlUotesDatas.clear();
mAlUotesDatas.addAll(res.data);
mUotesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This works fine. It was surprising for me, how this works??, though both have the updated data after web service call.

Can anyone help me to understand how this can be.?

This is  my class.

```
package com.mimran.aphorismus.models;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.mimran.aphorismus.R;
import com.mimran.aphorismus.adapters.QuotesAdaptor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRcvQuotes;
private QuotesAdaptor mUotesAdaptor;
private ArrayList<BillBoardData> mAlUotesDatas;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRcvQuotes = (RecyclerView) links(R.id.rcv_quotes);
    mUotesAdaptor = new QuotesAdaptor(mContext, mAlUotesDatas);
    mRcvQuotes.setAdapter(mUotesAdaptor);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);
}

public void webserviceCall() {
    public void onResponse ()
    {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            mAlUotesDatas.clear();
            //mAlUotesDatas = (ArrayList<BillBoardData>) res.data;
            mAlUotesDatas.addAll(res.data);
            mUotesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you don't add items to proper instance of data collection.

`Adapter` is initialized in a constructor with the specific instance of data collection and it's working on it all the time.

After this:

```
 mAlUotesDatas = (ArrayList<BillBoardData>) webservice.data;
```

`mAlUotesDatas` is a reference to different collection than `Adapter`'s instance.

Then:

```
mUotesAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

actually notify adapter about changes in *"old"* data collection which hasn't changed.

When you use `clear` and `addAll` it works because you work with the same instance and you're replacing items inside it.